# Question about the behavior in which $\cos x$ repeats in the interval $[0,2\pi]$.

Tags: trigonometry

It's obvious to see that $\cos x$ repeats every $2\pi$ values of $x$. However if you look at $\cos x$ in the interval $[0,2\pi]$:

[image: cosine]

Than you can see that cosine repeats (in this specific interval) in such a way that cannot be described by the simple equation:

$$\cos(x+2\pi)=\cos(x)$$

My question is can you find an function $g(x)$ st. :

$$\cos(x)=\cos(x+g(x))$$ in $$[0,2\pi]$$

I know that $g(0)=2\pi$ works, $g(\pi)=0$, and $g(\pi/2)=\pi$  works.

I thought of using angle sum:

$$\cos(x)=\cos(x)\cos(g(x))-\sin(x)\sin(g(x))$$

But could not get anywhere. Help and hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're wrong. $\cos x = cos(x + 2 \pi)$ is universally true. PLot the graph over a larger domain and break the domain up into pieces: $[0, 2\pi], [2\pi, 4\pi], [4\pi, 6\pi] \dots$ It should be pretty obvious

Comment: $g(x) = 2\pi - 2x$ works. (Since $\cos$ is even and $2\pi$-periodic.)

Comment: I know it's true but I want to see how $cos(\pi/2)=cos(3\pi/2)=0$ can be described in terms of $cos(x+g(x))=cos(x)$ Because I notice, $\pi/2 \neq \pi/2+2\pi$. I'm only considered about the interval $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: How did you get the $2x$ though? @Daniel Fischer

Comment: I wanted $x + g(x) = 2\pi - x$.

Comment: I see I forgot about the added $x$ for $x+g(x)$, thanks.

Comment: @wuyudi  Will you please stop editing by replacing '\pi' with an image of it, and stop replacing '\lambda' with a copy and paste of an image of it, and stop replacing `\infty` with a copy and paste of an image of the symbol.  You are correct to add back-slashes before trig functions, but when you edit, you undermine just as much as you attempt to fix.